# Create one pdf out of multiple (selected) images

Tags: pdf, image-manipulation

To convert multiple images to pdf this script will do that for all images inside a folder:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
for f in *.png; do
  convert ./"$f" ./"${f%.png}.pdf"
done
```

But each image is converted into a separate file.

Can all images be converted into one single pdf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source [here, to **Generate PDF file from any set of documents**](http://bernaerts.dyndns.org/linux/74-ubuntu/338-ubuntu-generate-pdf-from-documents), not only images.

From the above source:

> Main principle
>
> When you want to generate a multi-pages PDF file from multiple
>   documents, you need to follow few steps :
>
> ```
> Sort of all input documents in alphabetical order
> Convert them to some temporary PDF files
> Assemble all temporary PDF documents to a final multi-pages PDF document.
> ```
>
> Conversion of input documents to temporary PDF format should be done
>   according to their mimetype :
>
> ```
> Image files (jpg, png, tiff, …)
> Plain text files (txt)
> Libre Office & Open Office documents (odt, ods, …)
> Microsoft Office files (doc, docx, xls, xlsx, ppt, pptx, …)
> ```
>
> Depending on input document types, conversion to PDF should be done
>   using specific tools :
>
> ```
> convert (from ImageMagick) for image files
> unoconv for Libre Office, Microsoft Office and plain text files
> ```
>
> Once all input documents are converted to some temporary PDF files,
>   final document assembly is done using GhostScript. This powerful tool
>   allows to :
>
> ```
> merge multiple PDF documents
> optimize final file size
> ```

For Nautilus and Gnome see more details at the above link, which includes more scripts to automate the processes needed. I have used a more limited approach, as the solution is streamlined for Gnome ad Nautilus and I use mainly KDE and Dolphin.

This solution gives the results requested in the question but is intended to also be applied to **text documents and pdfs (beside images)** and to merge them all into the final pdf.

The files are integrated into the output pdf **in alphabetical order**.

The final context-menu command can be also applied **to the folder containing all the files** to be merged.

The solution also includes some **GUI** features.

So:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick unoconv ghostscript zenity libfile-mimeinfo-perl
```

Using `gedit` or other text editor:

```
gedit ~/.config/pdf-generate.conf
```

And paste this:

```
[general]
compression=95
density=200
```

So if you want to modify any default parameter, just edit this file before running the tool.

Main script in charge of the PDF generation k=job should be placed under `/usr/local/bin/pdf-generate`. See source link for the content of the main script. (Also [here](http://pastebin.com/0rrVvJLQ).)

You can install main script and its configuration file from command line :

```
# mkdir --parents $HOME/.config
# wget --header='Accept-Encoding:none' -O $HOME/.config/pdf-generate.conf https://raw.githubusercontent.com/NicolasBernaerts/ubuntu-scripts/master/pdf/pdf-generate.conf
# sudo wget --header='Accept-Encoding:none' -O /usr/local/bin/pdf-generate https://raw.githubusercontent.com/NicolasBernaerts/ubuntu-scripts/master/pdf/pdf-generate
# sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/pdf-generate
```

To fully integrate this PDF generation tool in your desktop environment:

```
gedit /usr/share/applications/pdf-generate.desktop.
```

See link for Gnome/Nautilus integration and automated download and installation. A slightly simplified and adjusted version for my KDE needs:

```
    [Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=pdf-generate
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
Icon=pdf
Keywords=pdf;generate;image;office;document;merge
StartupNotify=true
Name[en_US]=Generate PDF document
Name[en]=Generate PDF document
Name[C]=Generate PDF document
Name[fr_FR]=Génération d'un PDF
Comment=Tool to merge a set of documents to a PDF file.
Comment[en_US]=Tool to merge a set of documents to a PDF file.
Comment[fr_FR]=Outil de concaténation de documents en un fichier PDF.
MimeType=image/bmp;image/gif;image/jpeg;image/jpg;image/png;image/tiff;application/pdf;application/x-pdf;application/x-bzpdf;application/x-gzpdf;application/msword;application/vnd.ms-word;application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text;application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document;application/vnd.ms-excel;application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.template;application/vnd.ms-powerpoint;application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation;application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.template;application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideshow;text/plain;
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Graphics;Conversion;Utility;
```

To get a full desktop integration, this PDF generation tool should be **available from a custom action in the file manager context menu**.

For Nautilus you  need to declare the new custom action in a .desktop file placed under `~/.local/share/file-manager/actions` (see link for content). For Dolphin/KDE it is in `~/.kde/share/kde4/services/ServiceMenus/`. Therefore, I did:

```
gedit ~/.kde/share/kde4/services/ServiceMenus/pdf-generate.desktop
```

with the content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Actions=pdf-generate
Encoding=UTF8
Icon=pdf
MimeType=MimeTypes=image/bmp;image/gif;image/jpeg;image/jpg;image/png;image/tiff;application/pdf;application/x-pdf;application/x-bzpdf;application/x-gzpdf;application/msword;application/vnd.ms-word;application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text;application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document;application/vnd.ms-excel;application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.template;application/vnd.ms-powerpoint;application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation;application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.template;application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideshow;text/plain;inode/directory;application/pdf
ServiceTypes=KonqPopupMenu/Plugin
Type=Service


[Desktop Action pdf-generate]
Exec=pdf-generate %F
Icon=pdf
Name=Create pdf file
```

After re-login, a context menu option appears when selecting files, as indicated in the source link. For my KDE/Dolphin configuration, this works for selected files if they have the same extension. Otherwise, the best way it just to put all needed files in one folder and then execute the command from the right-click context menu of that folder.

[image]

Testing on a folder containing a png, a jpeg, a pdf and an odt file:

[image]

[image]

The output file is in the source folder, with the name `first_in_alphabetical_order-merged.pdf`.

[image]

Comment: Works great! On Arch, I had to fiddle with some XML file, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52998331/imagemagick-security-policy-pdf-blocking-conversion

Comment: The after the wget commands are broken. And also the topmost link with the article. This may be salvagable by referring to a correct version on github...

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `-adjoin` option of `convert`:

```
convert -adjoin *.png out.pdf
```

This command will result in one `pdf` file with all the `png` images.

Comment: can `-adjoin` be added as such to the the script in the question?

Comment: @cipricus What's the problem with Marius's command? If the problem is that you're collecting the input file names one at a time, why not store them into an array and process the whole array when you've finished collecting them?

Comment: @Gilles - It works if run in terminal inside the folder containing the image files. I was just trying to use his command in a context menu files manager action like I was doing with the script mentioned in the question. - On the other hand I have found a very comprehensive solution that I have presented in a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

### Updated:

What I have used most recently in Dolphin is this service menu:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Service
Actions=image2pdf
Icon=application-pdf
Encoding=UTF-8
TryExec=img2pdf
ServiceTypes=KonqPopupMenu/Plugin
MimeType=image/*

[Desktop Action image2pdf]
Exec=konsole -e img2pdf %F -o out.pdf
Icon=application-pdf
Name=Convert selected image(s) into single pdf
```

as said [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1004158/925128). (To fix problems with proper numbering of the files, see [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/666053/341192).)

---

```
sudo apt install imagemagick
```

Create a context menu for the file manager, for example a "Service Menu" for Dolphin; `~/.local/share/kservices5/ServiceMenus/IMG_2_PDF.desktop`:
4pPtqnJTDYShMf3
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Service
ServiceTypes=KonqPopupMenu/Plugin
MimeType=image/*;
Actions=pdf;

```
[Desktop Action pdf]
Name=Create PDF from images
Icon=application-pdf
Exec=bash -c 'convert %F  out.pdf'
```

For any file manager that supports context menu actions, the important lines are:

```
MimeType=image/*;
Exec=bash -c 'convert %F out.pdf'
```

***Be sure you are not affected by the [ImageMagick security policy 'PDF' blocking conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59193253/12141355).***

---

Using Gthumb (not all viewers can print *multiple* images to file):

- select the images, right click them and open them all in gThumb (they will be displayed as in a file browser, not in the image viewer);

[image]

**One can even re-arange the images before creating the pdf!**

Just drag & drop:

[image]

- in order to print them, select them again, right-click them, select "Print";

[image]

- select location where to save the file and in the list of printers select "Print to file".

[image]

Other image viewers that can print multiple images to pdf:

- [Xnview MP](https://www.appimagehub.com/p/1170376)

---

(By the way, I am the OP and author of another answer too (now signed `user32012`): I have deleted my account at some point and now I'm back.)