# img2pdf: get pages in good order

Tags: rename, sort, konsole

`img2pdf` works very quickly with hundreds of images and creates a pdf out of them with a command like

```
img2pdf *.tif -o out.pdf
```

but the page order is wrong in my case. I ran the command in `konsole` under Kubuntu 20.04.

The image files are named (renamed in Dolphin file manager) in the form

```
Vol_1.tif
Vol_2.tif
Vol_3.tif
...
Vol_430.tif
```

The resulting pdf starts with the file/page called `Vol_100.tif` which makes some sense (100 is seen before 1 or 11). Then, the one called `Vol_119.tif` is followed by `Vol_11.tif`, `Vol_129.tif` is followed by `Vol_12.tif` ... ...`Vol_189.tif` is followed by `Vol_18.tif`.

How to proceed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your best option is to rename the files so that they all have the same number of zero-padded digits, using the perl `rename` utility (this has different names on different distros, including `perl-rename`, `prename`, `file-rename`).  For example:

```
rename -n 's/^(Vol_)(\d+)/sprintf "%s%03i", $1, $2/e' Vol_*.tif
```

Change `%03i` to `%04i` or `%05i` if three digit zero-padding is not enough.

This uses the `-n` option, so will only show what would be renamed.  If/when you're certain it does what you want, either remove the `-n` to silently rename the files (no output except on errors), or replace it with `-v` for verbose operation.

With `-v`, you'll see output like this:

```
$ rename -v 's/^(Vol_)(\d+)/sprintf "%s%03i", $1, $2/e' Vol_*.tif
Vol_1.tif renamed as Vol_001.tif
Vol_2.tif renamed as Vol_002.tif
Vol_50.tif renamed as Vol_050.tif
Vol_60.tif renamed as Vol_060.tif
```

---

Another option is to perform a natural sort on the filenames, so you'll need to use GNU `find`, `sort`, and `xargs` (or other versions with support for NUL separators):

e.g.

```
find . -name 'Vol_*.tif' -print0 | sort -z -V | xargs -0r img2pdf -o out.pdf
```

GNU sort's `-V` option is a "version" sort, which is their name for a natural sort.

Comment: Thunar file manager has a rename utility that can do that too.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the shell to expand the filenames in the correct order.

In bash, you can use brace expansion if you know the number range:

```bsh
img2pdf Vol_{1..430}.tif -o out.pdf
```

Or using regular wildcards, just say you want single-digit numbers first:

```bsh
img2pdf Vol_?.tif Vol_??.tif Vol_???.tif -o out.pdf
```